# How to assert every action in a function

Tags: python

Im writing a small script with selenium that is going to check if all links and forms on a simple website is working properly. For that im using assert before every action to make sure that every step is completed before moving on to the next action. This does not look too elegant with all these repetitive lines.

I was hoping there would be a way to run assert before every line in a function?
Does anyone have a tip for me on how to improve this! Thank you in advance! :)

The code looks like this:

```
try: 
    #Test all links
    assert find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT,"Get in touch"), back()
    assert find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT,"All projects"), back()
    assert find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT,"About me"), back()
    assert find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT,"Contact me"), back()
    assert find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT,"Logout"), back()

    #Get form
    driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/register")

    #fill reg. form
    assert fill_form_by_name(By.NAME, "username", f"{random}teser@tester.com")
    assert fill_form_by_name(By.NAME, "password", f"{random}tester123")
    find_and_click(By.NAME, "submit")
    assert (driver.current_url == "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login") 

    #fill form
    assert fill_form_by_name(By.NAME, "nm", f"{random}teser@tester.com")
    assert fill_form_by_name(By.NAME, "psw", f"{random}tester123")
    assert find_and_click(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/form/button")

    #Check if user was in session and logout
    driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
    assert find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT,"Contact me")
    assert (driver.current_url == "http://127.0.0.1:5000/contact") , back()
    assert find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT,"Logout"), back()

    return True
except: 
    print("Something happend - an error has occurred ")
    return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there were a simple way, you would still have to tag which lines require the assertion, because *not* eery line uses `assert`.

You can, however, reduce some of the boilerplate. For example, your first block has 5 identical assertions that differ only by the text to click. You can refactor this to iterate over a list of texts, using `all` to assert that they are all true. A generator can ensure that `all` stops as soon as the first function returns `False`.

```
texts = ["Get in touch", "All projects", "About me", "Contact me", "Logout"]
assert all(find_and_click(By.LINK_TEXT, x) for x in texts), back()
```

Comment: shouldn't `back()` be called after every `find_and_click()`?  I presume it navigates to a new page.

Comment: No, because in the original the `AssertionError` raised by one `False` result skips the following calls. `all` does the same thing: it stops iterating as soon as it sees one `False` result, skipping the following calls. Even in the original, `back` is called *once* before the `AssertionError` transfers control to the `except` block. If that's a problem, it's a problem in the original code as well.

Comment: Fair.  I assumed the op didn't mean what they wrote (i.e. that `,` was just a shorthand for multiline statements), which is rude in retrospect and founded on nothing.  apologies to the op!

Comment: Nope, special syntax :) `assert` has to be a special statement, not a regular function, because `assert(find_and_click(...), back())` would have to evaluate both arguments fully before `assert` could test the result and print its second argument. As a statement, `assert` can test the condition, *then* decide if `back` should be called.

Comment: Yes indeed.  I glossed it for some reason as 'that's not what they meant' purely because I imagine needing to go back after every click.  And did so without even noticing I'd done it.  Assumptions making an ass (donkey in Britain) out of me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add `assert` before every line in a function.  Moreover, even if there were (and if it were able to specify 'line' a bit better, so it didn't bail on things like `assert for x in y:`, it would be of dubious usefulness: generally you solve repetitive problems by doing something like parametrising the test and writing one function which can call a bunch of tests.  This is the obvious solution here, and I'll come to it in a moment.  Other solutions include:

### writing a wrapper fn:

```py
def call_assert(f, *args, msg="", **kwargs):
    assert f(*args, **kwargs), msg
```

### Putting your test cases in a data structure and looping over them:

```py
for text in {"About me", "Contact me"}:
    call_assert(find_and_click, (By.LINK_TEXT, text), msg=f"{text} failed")
    back()
```

### Using `pytest.mark.parametrize`

By this point we've basically reinvented [the wheel](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html).  So we do something like:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def page():
    # put real code here
    yield the_page_we_use
    back()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("text", {"About me", "Contact me"})
def test_click(page, text):
    assert find_and_click(page, By.LINK_TEXT, text), text)
```

As always, using a ready made wheel can be a little harder than making your own at the beginning, but it pays off. In this case the page should really be a fixture, and `find_and_click` should take a specific page.  The fixture then takes care of running `back()` for us later, leaving the thing being tested in a known state.

Of course, you have to run these tests with pytest!